A Middle-Eastern color film where a boy is trapped inside a burning building
It was a Middle-Eastern film. I cannot recall which language but it was a language from that region.  It was not animated, it was in color, it was most likely a drama, and the film was probably made before the nineties as I saw this film on Finnish television in the nineties.
The only scene that I recall is about a fire in an apartment building.  A dark-haired boy is inside the building in his home alone and wonders how to escape the fire.  The boy can walk and talk so I assume his age is at least 5 years but not more than 15 years old.  The boy's mother (and possibly other family too) is outside looking up at the building and the mother cries the boy's name in anxiety: "Ari Muhammad" or "Ali Muhammad".  I recall the mother wearing a scarf around her head, face was visible, she was not thin, age 40+.  The scene switches back and forth between the mother on the ground and the boy inside the building.
